# How to install LLVM Clang on an iPad?

Tags: ipad, clang, llvm

I want to get LLVM (Clang) on my iPad so I could compile Objective-C with my iPhone. But

1. I don't know which binary I should download (FreeBSD? Debian? MAC?)
2. I don't know how to install it on my iPad using terminal commands.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have compiled clang/llvm for iOS and it successfully runs on my iPod Touch 2G and my iPad 2. It is available from the following repo: http://ininjas.com/repo/

If you like it or have any comments, check out the forum at http://ininjas.com/forum/

Comment: Can you explain how you were able compile compile Clang? I have been trying to compile it myself, but didn't succeed. Your help would be much appreciated. (Also, I tried to register in your forum, but I was accused of being spam.)

Comment: I am working on making a GitHub clone repo that contains the patched version. This won't happen overnight, but it will happen. I've been talking with DHowett about the patches as well. If you're having trouble registering, just email me: c0deh4cker@ininjas.com

Comment: Please let me know when the repo is online. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @C0deH4cker I added this repo, and there is nothing listed re: clang, llvm, or gcc.

Comment: Try it now. I forgot that I moved it to the beta repo because I forgot to sign it. I moved it back though. For all future questions about this, please direct them to the forum (link in answer) because SO isnt a discussion site, but a forum is.

Comment: @c0deh4cker does clang 3.1 from your repo make the device freeze on reboot like Richard pointed out in his anwer?

Comment: @Maxner: No. This does not happen and cannot happen. Installing clang in no way changes how your device boots, nor should it. One thing that I want everybody to know: I am no longer the maintainer of this package, so please don't ask me about it. I am also no longer affiliated with iNinjas.

Comment: @C0deH4cker really? Who is maintaining the repo then?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: You can't.

Long answer: 
You can get an older version of GCC, but it was removed from the public cydia repos as For some reason it makes the device crash on boot with iOS 4+.

If you really want GCC, here is a google code project:
http://code.google.com/p/iphone-gcc-full/

Comment: Note: To install software other that the available on the appstore you'll to jailbreak your ipad. Once you have it jailbreaked you'll need a terminal, the fastesy is to install openSSH from Cydia and connect from your PC/Mac.

Comment: @fbernardo He already said that he wanted to use terminal commands, so I assumed he was jailbroken.

Comment: thank you, but i hope you can teach me how to compile code in the terminal with something else.